# A strange question on fread, offset don't match the document

Tags: c++

```
//encrypt data
void EncryptBlock(unsigned char*& blockdata, size_t n)
{
}

//encrypt file
bool EncryptFile(const char* path, size_t blocksize)
{
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    auto erno = fopen_s(&fp, path, "rb+");
    if (erno != 0)
    {
        printf("openfile:[%s] fail!!, errno=%d\n", path, erno);
        return false;
    }

    //get file size
    _fseeki64(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int64_t filesize = _ftelli64(fp);
    _fseeki64(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("filesize:%lld, %lldmb\n", filesize, filesize / (1024 * 1024));

    int64_t processed = 0;
    //buffer
    unsigned char* blockdata = new  unsigned char[blocksize];
    while (1)
    {
        int64_t currpos = _ftelli64(fp);
        //printf("curr:%lld, size=%lldmb\n", currpos, currpos / (1024 * 1024));

        //read and set offset 
        size_t readsize = fread(blockdata, 1, blocksize, fp);
        int64_t currpos2 = _ftelli64(fp);
        if (currpos + readsize != currpos2)
        {
            return false;
        }
        _fseeki64(fp, -1 * readsize, SEEK_CUR);

        //encrypt
        EncryptBlock(blockdata, readsize);

        //write
        size_t writesize = fwrite(blockdata, 1, readsize, fp);
        if (writesize != readsize)
        {
            printf("write:writesize=%llu, readsize=%llu, warning!!!!!!!!!!!\n", writesize, readsize);
        }
        processed += writesize;

        if (readsize != blocksize)
        {
            printf("readsize=%llu, block=%llu, break[processd:%llu]\n", readsize, blocksize, processed);
            break;
        }
    }
    delete[] blockdata;
    fclose(fp);

    //error
    if (processed != filesize)
    {
        printf("processed(%lld) != filesize(%lld), warning!!!!!!!!!!!\n", processed, filesize);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto tv1 = GetTickCount64();
    auto suc = EncryptFile("d:\\soft.msi", 1024 * 102);
    auto tv2 = GetTickCount64();

    auto used = (tv2 - tv1);
    printf("encrypt：%s, cost：%llums\n", suc ? " succ" : " fail", used);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**please use a file larger than 20MB**

EncryptFile("path", 1024 * 1024) or EncryptFile("path", 1024 * 4) is correct

EncryptFile("path", 1024 * 102) is incorrect

The second cycle will come into `if (currpos + readsize != currpos2)`

i use windows10(vs2015) and Ubuntu20(gcc 9.3.0) is same phenomenon

https://i.loli.net/2021/07/08/Tdt4ocLsw9Mgn3R.gif

I think the reason for the mistake should be my misunderstanding of fread, fwrite and ftell. [microsoft.docs.fread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fread?view=msvc-160) say `The file pointer associated with stream (if there is one) is increased by the number of bytes actually read.`

Comment: What are the actual values of `currpos`, `readsize` and `afterFread` when it fails?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That's not a VLA, that's a call to `new[]`.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Ooops.

Comment: Also, the file _is_ opened in binary mode.

Comment: @Afshin  Looks like I out on at least 2 of 4 ideas.  Time for sleep.  Think I'll take them all down.  TTFN

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - Early to bed and early to rise makes a man healthy, wealthy and wise... `:)`

Comment: The only thing "C++" in this question is the `new` / `delete`... perhaps get a tutorial that actually teaches C++? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `fseek` between `fwrite` and `fread`.

[The standard says](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7)

> output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek, fsetpos, or rewind), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end- of-file.

Comment: I've tried both methods, and they both work. thanks